# What is this long, thin green pepper?

Tags: identification, peppers

I think I got the wrong kind of pepper. On the tag it says they are ready at 10cm and yellow. Now they are still green and nearly 30 cm!

What kind of pepper is this and how do I know when it's ready?

[image]

This is the tag:

[image]

Comment: So, I'm not the only one who get mostly the wrong pepper plants.  I think this question is difficult: from a photo it is impossible to get the variety (and possibly it is not a true variety), and so the second part of the question is difficult,  but I hope someone will give you (and me) some general indications. Usually I wait too much.

Comment: What kind does the tag say it is?

Comment: I worked in a garden centre for a couple of years and often found wrong tags on plants, especially if they're those firm plastic tags that are pushed into the soil near the pot's rim. People often pull out the tag to read the info and shove it back in any pot around. Or they leave it lying about and clueless workers shove them back in the wrong pot. I've occasionally seen plants come in with the wrong tags too. It's likely not your fault.

Comment: I added the tag

Comment: @Jude You should make that an answer IMO. :)

Comment: @Shule Thanks but mine isn't an answer since he already figured it wasn't the variety he thought he bought. He asked if anyone knew what it might be too and I'm clueless about long thin hot pepper cultivars. Yours is the better answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Cheyenne Orange is an F1 hybrid, it's possible that they let the mother plant pollinate itself on accident. Maybe this is the mother variety of the cross.

Lacking that, it could be a mutation or mixed up seed, but which is anyone's guess. In all three scenarios, it could potentially breed true. If it doesn't breed true, I'm sure it's not the mother of the cross.

Your pepper looks similar to Corbaci, except Corbaci is more twisty and doesn't start green (it starts yellow).

To know when it's ready, since it's an unfamiliar kind of pepper, you may just have to taste it at every color phase and decide for yourself. However, if it is the mother of the cross, you might use Cheyenne Orange's instructions as a guideline in you experiments (since it could share a lot of its genetics). I'm guessing they usually harvest Cheyenne Orange when orange. This may or may not turn orange, but it should turn at least one color.

Make sure the fruit is full-sized when you harvest it if you harvest it green.

It could be Cow Horn, maybe, or some kind of Cayenne (Cheyenne is spelled a lot like Cayenne, anyhow; it would make sense for Cayenne to be the mother of the cross here). Cheyenne Orange F1 has a similar Scoville rating as Cayenne.

Another alternative (perhaps more likely) is that whoever grew the plants bought [Cheyenne F1 pepper](http://www.burpee.com/vegetables/peppers/pepper-hot-cheyenne-hybrid-prod003164.html) seeds and assumed they were Cheyenne Orange F1 when in fact they were not. Cheyenne and Cheyenne Orange are different varieties, but the seller may have only heard of Cheyenne Orange.

Comment: it looks a lot like cow horn pepper! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer but it is easier to send a link.  This guy is growing only peppers in this video.  He also does lots of other garden videos and he is real...kind of cute, I don't go by all he says but most is good.  But watch this video and all the different peppers.  Makes me want to grow even more peppers!  He grabs peppers that look like yours and eats them; crunch crunch crunch...great resource.  Perhaps this will help for now?[pepper growing dude](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zH0Jztqt5TY)